# Is MD5 Hash of current-time in milliseconds Time ordered?

Tags: md5

I am generating a MD5 hash of current time.
Example :

```
md5Hex(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Will this be time ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not.

While MD5 isn't the best hash function, a fundamental property of cryptographic hash functions is that (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)):

> "a small change to a message should change the hash value so
> extensively that a new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old
> hash value (avalanche effect)"

For the hashes of a series of times to be time-ordered, the hash function would need to show predictable changes (consistent increases) in response to changing input (the increasing time) - and this contradicts the properties that a cryptographic hash function needs to have.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing predictable about the result of encoding an md5, so the answer is **no**. Demonstration example in php:

```
$t0 = 0;
for($x=0;$x<100;$x++)
{
    $t = hexdec(md5($x));
    if($t0) {
        print($x.'- inc:'.($t - $t0)."\n");
    }
    $t0 = $t;
}
```

output

```
1- inc:-1.4636401260253E+37
2- inc:4.4248172124663E+36
3- inc:4.8752218278229E+37
4- inc:-9.0781185652814E+37
5- inc:8.0222386433686E+37
6- inc:-2.7432564192114E+38
7- inc:1.6031661269927E+38
8- inc:7.8237939004744E+37
9- inc:-1.7568874255319E+38
10- inc:1.8885794520725E+38
11- inc:-1.4724589530448E+38
12- inc:1.2357714342155E+38
13- inc:4.0814541080975E+36
14- inc:-3.5109024028024E+37
...
```